# How to run commands in command prompt through robot framework?

Tags: android-emulator, appium, robotframework, command-prompt

How to run commands like 'appium' and 'emulator -list-avds' in the command prompt through robotframework.

I have tried keywords like *Run* from *Operating System library* and *Run process* from *Process library*. However, they are not working. I am not getting any errors from these keywords and the commands are not getting executed.

Comment: How do you know they are not getting executed?

Comment: The appium server has not started and the android virtual device has not started.

Comment: I have android studio installed and I want to launch the android virtual device through cmd using the command 'emulator -avd Pixel_4_Android_11'. I want this command to be run in the cmd through robot framework.

Comment: Please edit your question, by adding the exact robot steps you used to call the emulator launch.

Comment: Please find below the code
`*** Settings ***
Library  OperatingSystem
Library  AppiumLibrary
*** Test Cases ***
User Should run commands
      Run  appium
      Run  emulator -avd Pixel_4_Android_11`